# Adding geom_rect to a geom_bar plot with a dataset containing factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a data set (All_Rain_sub) which has a location name along with three values - rainfall for the month, yesterday, and last three days. I used the melt function to create a long dataset

```
All_Rain_melt<-melt(All_Rain_sub, id.vars = "station_name")
```

The All_Rain_melt has the following structure:

```
$ station_name: Ord.factor w/ 129 levels "129. Main Office"<..: 129 128 127 126 125 124 123 122 121 120 ...
 $ variable    : Factor w/ 3 levels "yesterday","threeDay",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ..
```

I used the code below to create a barplot such that the order of the X-axis does not change. The reason is that the locations are ordered such that those in the north are first then central and then south:

```
All_Rain_melt$station_name<-factor(All_Rain_melt$station_name, levels = rev(unique(All_Rain_melt$station_name)), ordered = TRUE)

All_Rain_melt %>%
  arrange(-value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=station_name, y=value, fill=variable, width=0.5))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "identity")+coord_flip()+ 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(0,4,by=0.5),limits = c(0,4),sec.axis = dup_axis())+
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.key.height = unit(0.5,"cm"), legend.key.width = unit(2,"cm"),legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.5), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "white"),
        axis.line = element_line(), axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=5))
```

The bar plot looks the way I want but now I want to add geom_rect for locations 1 to 30 (locations 1 to 30 are in the northern region), locations 31 to 63 (central), and locations 64 to 129 (south) in different colors. When I add geom_rect, ggplot 2 doesn't keep the order of the X-axis and reorders it alphabetically. Is there a way around this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what code you're using to add the geom_rect to understand why it might not be working yet. Here's an example using two related ways to plot `geom_rect` to the numeric value of the y axis, which is here an ordered factor.

The `annotate` syntax is useful for a one-off, while using a separate tibble as the data source for `geom_rect` can be a good way to perform calculations and organize a longer set of coordinates.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  head() %>%
  rownames_to_column("car") %>%
  mutate(car = fct_reorder(car, wt)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes( wt, car)) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 0, xmax = 3, ymin = 0.5, ymax = 2.5, fill = "red", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_rect(data = tibble(xmin = 0, xmax = 3.5, ymin = 2.5, ymax = 3.5),
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), fill = "green", alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]